How to use a PostgreSQL table as a task queue, with attempt counts
Each row of my table tasks is a task, and I have N concurrently running task processors.
tasks {
   creation_time: timestamp,
   processing_attempts: smallint,
   # ... <more fields related to the task>
}

The tasks are unsanitized user input, so I should be prepared for anything, even crashes on the processor. I want each processor to select the oldest unlocked row with less than K processing attempts (I could do that with SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED).
Then I want to immediately increment (and commit) the processing_attempts, so that if this process crashes, the culprit task already has a mark, which if it reaches K, will exclude it from the queue. Then I want to continue processing the task without the risk of another processor taking it.
Apparently this can't be done inside a transaction, because it seems there is no way to commit and keep the exclusive lock on the row (i.e. commit and immediately start a new transaction with the same locks).
So, what would be the solution for me here that:

Just one processor gets one task;
Once a task is taken by a processor, if the session ends unexpectedly, its processing_attempts will be necessarily incremented.


Consider adding a column to record state with values such as ready, active, failed,  completed, and cancelled. Use UPDATE tasks SET status = 'active, processing_attempts = processing_attempts + 1 WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM tasks WHERE status IN ('ready', 'failed') AND processing_attempts < max_attempts ORDER BY creation_time LIMIT 1 RETURNING *` to get the next runnable task.

@JohnH The subselect is missing a for update skip locked, the rest is a great idea. I guess you skipped it because the update locks the row anyways, but if the select doesn't do that skip, all concurrent processors would hang and wait for the first one to commit/rollback instead of reaching for other tasks. If you try to commit right after acquiring a task this way (no skip) the other processor would immediately kick off an unwanted, parallel attempt. Holding it open starts out of order attempts later. In both cases you may exceed max_attempts or even re-do an already completed task.

@Zegarek, I didn't notice that I had somehow deleted FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) between LIMIT 1 and RETURNING and also prematurely ended the code markdown. Those are the kinds of things that happen when one posts in a hurry.

Add an additional column started_processing of type timestamp with time zone with a default value of -infinity.
Whenever a processor grabs a task, it sets the column to the current_timestamp and commits right away. The column acts as a lock that can time out, so if the processor crashes, the row won't be locked for ever.
Processors search jobs with a query like
SELECT ...
FROM tasks
WHERE started_processing < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '5 minutes'
LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;

Here, 5 minutes stands for the maximum execution time that a task is allowed.

Great workaround.

After posting this question, I had an idea, which seems to be similar to @JohnH comment, but I am not sure.
I need two simultaneous connections to the database for it.
I add another table to hold the processing_attempts, and do the following:

From connection 1 start the transaction and SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;;
when I get the task, from connection 2 I UDPATE the processing_attempts for that task I got (or INSERT if missing) and commit;
From the same connection 2, I open a transaction and delete the row I just updated, but leave it open;
Then I process the task;
If everything went right, I delete the task via connection 1;
Commit both transactions.

I haven't tested it, and my fear is that the transactions would revert in SERIALIZABLE isolation level, because I would need to join both tables in order to get the task.
And after writing all this, it sounds a terrible idea.
